# Raspberry Pi 3 routing

Tags: networking, routing, lan, raspberry-pi

I have set static ip on eth0 to 192.168.1.10. To lan port I have connected device that has static IP 192.168.1.100.

Wlan0 is connected to wireless network with internet access and DHCP.

I want to set routing that all traffic goes via waln0 except connection to 192.168.1.100 that must go via eth0.

How do I do that?

Comment: This is the default. No need any configuration.

Comment: By default I cannot connect to internet or my device on lan.

Answer (score 0):

This seems doable but I will have to make some assumptions:

1. Your wireless connection using DHCP is represented by the network 192.168.1.0 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0
2. Your static IP assignments are using subnet mask 255.255.255.0

You can change your wired logical network to 192.168.2.0 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0. This means changing the eth0 address on the pi to 192.168.2.10 and the other device to 192.168.2.100. Your pi will then be able to reach the wired device by its IP and all other traffic will go through the gateway on your wireless connection.